# How to do an AJAX form submission WITH page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a HTML form that posts data to a Laravel/PHP login page.

When I use the native HTML form submission attributes like so:

```
<form name='login' class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="https://somewebsite.com/login">
   // form here
</form>
```

My form submits fine, and once it validates I am sent to a new accounts page (dictated by the site in the `action` attribute link.

However, I want to do some javascript processing before I send this form off, so I'd like to do it via jQuery. At the moment, I do:

```
  $("#form").submit(function(){
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: liveLink,
          data: dataObj,
          success: function(res, other, other2){
            // Do some javascript stuff in here

            // Then I would like to follow the URL with correct tokens sent back by the PHP page
          }
      });
    });
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: If you're not using `preventDefault()` or `return false;` the page should refresh. Honestly there is no need to use AJAX for this though.

Comment: Couldn't you just use: location.window.href = "http://website.com";  on your success function?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I need to do some analytics tracking before the form is sent off (and I also need to compile a JS object to send, do honeypot validation and so on). I *am* using preventDefault() / returning false on the original submit function, just left it out here for brevity. If I delete them will it do as I hope?

Comment: @Roots I've tried that, but it seems like Laravel gives some sort of special pass-through link which attaches a cookie / session to your browser before sending you to our actual CMS page. Either way, when I tried this I got sent to Laravel's nataive login page

Comment: What I might suggest is to bind your submit handler like you are with jQuery.  Immediately cancel the form submit.  Perform your extra javascript logic that you need.  Then, when you are ready for the form to actually submit, call `submit()` on the form dom Element itself, not the jquery object referencing the form.  This will cause the form to submit and bypass the jquery submit binding.

Comment: `location.window.href = "website.com";` will definately work on a Laravel site. Calling this will send all the same cookies to the server as would be if you put the url directly in the web browser. Are you sure that the route you are trying to redirect to has the proper middleware applied to it? ie does the route have the `web` and `auth` middlewares applied?

Comment: @Jascination man, then you have to disable session for that route. Have a look at this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-51-disable-session-and-cookies-for-some-routes

Comment: @Roots OP does not need to disable sessions, just needs to set the route up properly .

Comment: OP please post the exact error you get when trying `location.window.href = "YOUR URL";`

Comment: @JayBlanchard how would that fix anything? That's just going to make the form submit without running any of the needed javascript

Comment: My bad @DelightedD0D, just automatically responded without reading the additional comments.